# Linq-sql join two tables

Tags: linq-to-sql, join, lambda

I'm trying to join two tables in my database based off two values that exist in both tables (model and manufacturer), there is no fk relationship in the database for these values for various reasons.

So far I have the following:

```
var modelManufacturer = DataContext.Assets_ND.Select(a => new {a.ModelNo, a.Manufacturer}).Distinct();

var masterPMs = DataContext.MasterPlannedMaintenances.Where(pm => pm.PlantId == model.PlantId);

var joined = modelManufacturer.Join(masterPMs.AsEnumerable(), a => new {a.ModelNo, a.Manufacturer},pm => new {pm.Model, pm.Manufacturer}, x => new {x.ModelNo, x.Manufacturer, x.Id});
```

This doesn't compile and has the error

> Error 7   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.Join(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

This is where I'm a bit stumped as to how to specify the values, I've tried a few combinations of 
`modelManufacturer.Join<Asset, MasterPlannedMaintenance....>` but intellisense seems to suggest that isnt right, or at least the order I'm putting them in isn't corrrect.

What am I doing wrong or what is a better way to join these two tables based on two string fields and return 2 values from the left table (Model, Manufacturer) and one from the right (id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var joined = (from a in dc.table1
              join b in dc.table2 on a.id equals b.id into temp
              from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new {
                  a.Model,
                  a.Manufacturer,
                  t.ID
               });
```

This will do a left join on the two tables and only select two values from table1 and 1 from table 2.